# Simplest way to toggle a integer variable between two values

Tags: c

I have a variable `a` which can have only two values `x1` or `x2`. How to toggle `a` between these values. I came up with this. Any other more efficient way?

```
a = (a == x1 ? x2: x1);
```

Comment: How much simpler do you want it? Install an oracle as a sub-processor perhaps?

Comment: Define *simple*. Less code?

Comment: I assume `a` is initialized to either `x1` or `x2`, and this is the only thing that *ever* modifies it, right? Because this assumes that if the test condition *fails* it *was* `x2`. But its probably fine for what you need.

Comment: If the values are 0 and 1, `a = !a` will do nicely. Any chance you can rework your program's logic so it works with 0 and 1?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's (highly) unlikely to be your bottleneck, but you could use the `XOR` method:

```
togglex1x2 = (x1 ^ x2);     // This is the combined toggle value

a = x1;            // Initialise to either x1 or x2

a ^= togglex1x2;   // toggles

a ^= togglex1x2;   // toggles

...
```

[You should write code that is understandable first, and optimise only when you have measured a bottleneck (and then double checked it is where you think it is!), and if you optimise make sure you comment with reasoning. ]

Comment: Thanks. This is a good solution because it's not vulnerable to overflows AFAIK (bitwise XOR doesn't care about signs, right?)

Comment: Why write code that is difficult to understand in a couple of months time when you are not the original programmer and just doing maintenance?

Comment: most experienced devs know the XOR swap, but I agree: write code that is understandable first, optimise only when you have measured a bottleneck, and if you optimise make sure you comment with reasoning.

Comment: @H2CO3 thats a great question. I know *shifting* into a sign bit is UB, but bit-ops... now I have to look this up.

Comment: @MitchWheat - I agree that most devs know of that trick - but hey - why make life more difficult than necessary. Also some devs get consumed in micro optimisation and lose sight of the bigger picture - where even better optimisations/usability is more "profitable"

Comment: which is why I commented above.

Comment: This is great. No overflow concern. `xor` maps to hardware will be faster as well.

Comment: @VallabhPatade I thought `?:` "mapped to hardware" too. Or is it magic?

Comment: @VallabhPatade: It is possible to implement `?:` in hardware, for instance using the CMOVcc set of x86 instructions.  I don't know if that's the way most compilers work, but it's certainly an option.

Answer (score 8):

Try something like this. a will toggle between x1 and x2

```
a = (x1 + x2) - a;
```

Comment: ...and hope (x1+x2) < INT_MAX

Comment: What about `x1 - a + x2`? Although I think in most real cases, we already know x1 and x2 values, and just want to put the sum there honestly.

Comment: @LukeVo Sure. That is more apt. We avoid the integer overflow scenario

Answer (score 4):

It's very hard to predict which method is better without a context - the biggest unknown is in which way is this operation critical - is it latency bound (for .e.g if you're doing a long calculation with data dependencies that go through this code), or perhaps bandwidth critical (you're swapping many unrelated elements, and start to run your resources thin).

Tried to benchmark the solutions proposed here.
see this code for e.g.:

```
int main()
{
  int x1 = 123, x2 = 456;
  int x1_xor_x2 = x1 ^ x2;
  int a = x1;
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
      a = (a == x1 ? x2: x1);

  for (i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
      a ^= x1_xor_x2;

  printf ("a=%d\n", a); // prevent all this from being optimized out
}
```

becomes (gcc, with -O3):

```
0000000000400440 <main>:
 400440:       b8 10 27 00 00          mov    $0x2710,%eax         // loop counter
 400445:       ba c8 01 00 00          mov    $0x1c8,%edx         
 40044a:       be 7b 00 00 00          mov    $0x7b,%esi           // 123 in esi
 40044f:       b9 c8 01 00 00          mov    $0x1c8,%ecx          // 456 in ecx
 400454:       eb 12                   jmp    400468 <main+0x28>   
 400456:       66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
 40045d:       00 00 00 

 400460:       83 fa 7b                cmp    $0x7b,%edx
 400463:       89 ca                   mov    %ecx,%edx
 400465:       0f 45 d6                cmovne %esi,%edx            // conditional move
 400468:       83 e8 01                sub    $0x1,%eax
 40046b:       75 f3                   jne    400460 <main+0x20>

 40046d:       b8 10 27 00 00          mov    $0x2710,%eax
 400472:       66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)

 400478:       81 f2 b3 01 00 00       xor    $0x1b3,%edx
 40047e:       83 e8 01                sub    $0x1,%eax            // xoring
 400481:       75 f5                   jne    400478 <main+0x38>

 400483:       be 6c 06 40 00          mov    $0x40066c,%esi
 400488:       bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
 40048d:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
 40048f:       e9 9c ff ff ff          jmpq   400430 <__printf_chk@plt>
```

After adding time checks (and bumping the loop count to 100M), I get on my server (AMD Opteron 6272):

```
first: 0.089000s
second: 0.067000s
a=123
```

This is not very interesting though as there's no consumer of a that requires low latency data (so the calculations may buffer up and we're checking ALU BW, not latency)

Trying to add `sum += a` on every iteration resulted in increased delta in favor of the first -

```
first: 0.106000s
second: 0.066000s
```

But! since a simple add isn't very time consuming itself, tried using the reciprocal (float sum and `+= 1/a`) - this one would really need the data fast:

```
first: 0.014000s
second: 0.087000s
```

Finally, inversion :)

This goes to show that you can have different performance outcomes according to how a given operation 
in used in your program. There's not much sense in benchmarking a single method without the rest of the code (not that we don't so it, it's just that you need to take any result with a chunk of salt).

Of course, this is all for the sake of discussion, most likely this bit of code is not even remotely a bottleneck..

Comment: Um, who voted down? If you explain what's wrong i'll try to fix/add missing data

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to toggle an index between 0 and 1 and index an array with that:

```
int main() {
    int const values[] = {0x55, 0xaa};
    int selector = 0;

    selector ^= 1;                // toggle index
    int value = values[selector]; // select value
}
```

Comment: This is also future-resistant. If in the future OP wants to round-robin between 3, 4, or N values, just add to the array and change `selector ^= 1` to `selector = (selector+1)%N`.

Answer (score 2):

***So you benchmarked it and this is the bottleneck, right?***

Oh, well, nope... then just forget about efficiency. This is already a very small expression that is evaluated quickly.

By the way, there are other methods but I'm not sure that 1. they are really faster, 2. if they are faster, it really counts, 3. if they are slower, the readability penalty is a worthwhile tradeoff.

For example:

```
#define FIRST 42
#define SECOND 1337

/* initialize */
int x = FIRST;

/* toggle */
x = FIRST + SECOND - x;
```