# How to peek ahead when processing an input file (processing 2 lines)

Tags: c, file, fopen

When going through a text file line by line I would like to be able to look ahead to the next line and inspect it while working on the current line. I am working in the C language. I believe that `fseek()` or other similar functions would help me with this but I'm unsure and don't know how to use them. I would want to achieve something to the effect of:

```
    fp = fopen("test-seeking.txt", "r");

    while((fgets(line, BUFMAX, fp))) {
        // Peek over to next line
        nextline = ...;
        printf("Current line starts with: %-3.3s / Next line starts with %-3.3s\n",
               line, nextline);
    }
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Use `fgetc` and `ungetc` or just read in the next line.

Comment: read 1 line, then read one line and use a 2-depth buffer. The first line in your buffer being the current line, and the other being the next one.

Comment: WINAPI has Peek-series functions.

Comment: @iBug sorry what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you can use `fseek` and try something like this:

```
fp = fopen("test-seeking.txt", "r");

while ((fgets(line, BUFMAX, fp))) {
    // Get the next line
    fgets(nextline, BUFMAX, fp);

    // Get the length of nextline
    int nextline_len = strlen(nextline);

    // Move the file index back to the previous line
    fseek(fp, -nextline_len, SEEK_CUR); // Notice the - before nextline_len!

    printf("Current line starts with: %-3.3s / Next line starts with %-3.3s\n", line, nextline);
}
```

---

Another way is to use `fgetpos` and `fsetpos`, like this:

```
fp = fopen("test-seeking.txt", "r");

while ((fgets(line, BUFMAX, fp))) {
    // pos contains the information needed from
    //   the stream's position indicator to restore
    //   the stream to its current position. 
    fpos_t pos;

    // Get the current position
    fgetpos(fp, &pos);

    // Get the next line
    fgets(nextline, BUFMAX, fp);

    // Restore the position
    fsetpos(fp, &pos);

    printf("Current line starts with: %-3.3s / Next line starts with %-3.3s\n", line, nextline);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0):

The following code is inspired by @[Jean-François Fabre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6451573/jean-fran%c3%a7ois-fabre) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45938222/how-to-peek-ahead-when-processing-an-input-file-in-c#comment78834267_45938222). It will use a 2D character array `lineBuffer` which is used to hold the lines. The first read line is written to index 0 `lineBuffer[0]` and the second line to `lineBuffer[1]`. After that the writings are alternating between index 0 and 1 with the help of a [toggle variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18941053/8051589) `lineSel`. As last step the `curLine` pointer will be set to `nextLine`.

As result you can use `curLine` and `nextLine` within the loop.
If you have a file that consists of:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
...
```

You will work with:

```
curLine  = "line 1\n"
nextLine = "line 2\n"

curLine  = "line 2\n"
nextLine = "line 3\n"

...
```

See [live example with stdin instead of a file on ideone](https://ideone.com/GRMGaz).

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFMAX       256
#define CURLINE      0
#define NEXTLINE     1
#define TOGGLELINE   (CURLINE ^ NEXTLINE)

int main ()
{
   FILE* fp = fopen("test-seeking.txt", "r");

   char lineBuffer[2][BUFMAX];
   char* curLine;
   char* nextLine;
   int lineSel;

   if (fp != NULL)
   {
      if ((curLine = fgets(lineBuffer[CURLINE], BUFMAX, fp)))
      {
         for (lineSel = NEXTLINE;
              (nextLine = fgets(lineBuffer[lineSel], BUFMAX, fp));
              lineSel ^= TOGGLELINE)
         {
            printf("Current line: \"%s\" / Next line \"%s\"\n",
                   curLine, nextLine);

            curLine = nextLine;
         }
      }

      fclose(fp);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response to my question Andre! I just selected an answer as a solution.