# why is my loop function hanging when it reaches fgets();

Tags: c, loops

I am just trying to toggle on Board LED and listen to incoming Data from the terminal window at the same time, but the whole Loop function hangs when it reachs the `fgets()`, until I send something the the terminal window then it continues to loop. There must be something like "if Serial available , then start to read ??  Here is my Code, I'm new in Atmel studio

```
 #include <asf.h>
    #include <string.h>
   

 char incomingData [256];  

   
    // /**
    //  *  \brief Configure UART for debug message output.
    //  */
    static void configure_console(void)
    {
        const usart_serial_options_t uart_serial_options = {
            .baudrate = CONF_UART_BAUDRATE,
            #ifdef CONF_UART_CHAR_LENGTH
            .charlength = CONF_UART_CHAR_LENGTH,
            #endif
            .paritytype = CONF_UART_PARITY,
            #ifdef CONF_UART_STOP_BITS
            .stopbits = CONF_UART_STOP_BITS,
            #endif
        };
    
        //  /* Configure console UART. */
        sysclk_enable_peripheral_clock(CONSOLE_UART_ID);
        stdio_serial_init(CONF_UART, &uart_serial_options);
    }
    int main (void)
 {  
        /* Insert system clock initialization code here (sysclk_init()). */
    
        board_init();
        sysclk_init();
        configure_console();
        /* Insert application code here, after the board has been initialized. */
         
    gpio_set_pin_low(LED0_GPIO);
    while (1)
       
    {
        printf("Hello\r\n");
        gpio_toggle_pin(LED0_GPIO);
        fgets(incomingData,sizeof(incomingData),stdin);
        printf("%s\r\n",incomingData);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45938222

Comment: Hi Robert, sorry but this was not helpful, i tried  while(fgets(incomingData,sizeof(incomingData),stdin)!=NULL) , still got stucked

Comment: If you are waiting for inconstant input rather use an interrupt routine and keep the LED toggling in the infinite loop. Or check if the `stdin` is [empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26948723/checking-the-stdin-buffer-if-its-empty).

Comment: @a.raad: It sounds like you either didn't read the post I linked, or you didn't understand it.

Comment: What is `incomingData`? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: when i check the stdin, it is never empty, doenst matter if i send something through the terminal or not.    @RobertHarvey i read it but it seems i didnt understand it, can u edit my example so i would understand easier ?

Comment: Well, maybe it's time to revisit your assumptions.  There is [plenty of prior art](https://www.google.com/search?q=atmel+read+from+serial+port) on reading from a serial port using an Atmel board; I suggest you start there.

Comment: @RobertHarvey do you think i didnt try to search ? or i didnt spend time to solve the Problem ? if you dont want to help ,then  u dont need to comment anything , you could have showed by now how to fix it, it is only a couple lines but U NEED to make yourself important

Comment: No, I think you're using the wrong approach.  Carefully study one of the articles that explains how to do serial I/O with Atmel, and follow that approach.

Comment: The stdio.h functions aren't suitable for concurrent programming. If you need several things happening "at once" (or appearing to), you need to use lower level functions. You can just dig your way down into the ASF lib and grab or rewrite parts from the UART driver. Be aware that this lib is very badly written, so digging through its internals isn't easy. Might be easier to roll out your own UART driver from scratch by reading the manual.

Comment: Alternatively in this specific you could just update the LED from a cyclic timer interrupt.